# How to make aliases for different generation objects

Tags: angular

I am trying to avoid having relative paths in my angular project and decided to use aliases. Here is how the project structure looks so far:

```
src:.
+---app
|   +---modules
|   |   +---admin-data
|   |   |   \---components
|   |   |       \---admin-data
|   |   +---connection
|   |   |   +---models
|   |   |   +---others
|   |   |   \---shared
        ... others

|   \---shared
+---assets
\---environments
```

So whenever I want to make a new component for admin-data fx. I have to type: ng g c modules/admin-data/components/

This a very long url to have to type. How can I make it so that whenever a new item is generated, it would go to the appropriate folder of the module - fx. components will go to components, services would go to shared, etc.

I know of the existance of aliases in tsconfig.json as such:

```
"paths": {
      "@modules/*": ["app/modules/*"], 
    }
```

However this is only useful for imports as far as I understand. And I couldn't find anything similar to this online.

So what I am asking is, how could I make it so that instead of executing this command:

ng g c modules/admin-data/components/new-component

I could execute something like this:

ng g c @admin-data/new-component

Comment: little trick : run your commands from `src/app` and you get autocomplete through the Tabluation key.

Comment: Otherwise, you will have to create [schematics](https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2)